# how to create a scrolling div between side bar and the table container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a scroll bar between the sidebar and the table both are in different container I tried to implement it but only the table container is displaying with the scroll and sidebar is hidden.

In side bar there would around six rows and table container which have around around 24 columns.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 20%;
}

#main {
  height: 60%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
  
 .container{
  position:relative;
  }
 
.sidebar{

   width:30%;
   background-color:lightblue;
   height: 1000px;;
   float:left;
   margin-left: -625px;
   flex: 50%;
   }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row" id="row_id">
          "side bar content"
        </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
     </div>

  


    <div class='container-l'>
      <div id='container-table'>
        <table class="table"> 
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th> Area </th>
                <th> Country </th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
 
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>US</td>
              <td>North America </td>
              <td>US</td>
             </tr>  
             <tr>
              <td>US</td>
              <td>North America </td>
              <td>US</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
     </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: Add the { overflow-y: scroll; } style to the sidebar class instead of main.

Comment: Add `overflow-y: scroll;` to your sidebar

Comment: I can scroll at the bottom of the side bar but vertically I didn't get the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I did understand the question, but you can try using columns too, or wrap the containers in a display flex div

```css
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">

<!-- your code here -->
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="row" id="row_id">
          "side bar content"
        </div>
      </div> 
      </div>
     </div>
     
    <div class='container-l'>
      <div id='container-table'>
        <table class="table"> 
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Region</th>
                <th> Area </th>
                <th> Country </th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
 
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>US</td>
              <td>North America </td>
              <td>US</td>
             </tr>  
             <tr>
              <td>US</td>
              <td>North America </td>
              <td>US</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
     </div>
     
</div>
 </body>
```